# Buttons shift downwards in android studio when text excedes 1 line

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to put a bunch of buttons in a Grid Layout, and all of the buttons look fine until I put enough text in one for the text to move on to another line. The button that has 2 lines of text shifts down 10dp.

[Button is shifted down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0MX2.png)

The first button is one that is in the right spot, the second is shifted down.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/flavButt2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="Flavor2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/flavButt3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="Cookies n Cream" />
```

I was able to get the button to go back to the right spot by setting the top margin to -10dp, but that becomes a pain if I need to change the text on the buttons.

Why is the location even changing? I am still new to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give it a `layout_gravity`; This kind of gravity is to set it in relation to its parent. There's other kind, and its `gravity`... so when you use a `gravity` attribute, its gonna be applied just to its children.

```
        <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem...."/>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, fixed the problem!